# Swagger does not recognize WebAPI controller parameter with custom attribute [FromContent]

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger, swashbuckle

I want to have a custom attribute to parse data as stream and be testable with Swagger.

So I created controller which reads from `POST` body:

```cs
[SwaggerOperation("Create")]
[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created)]
public async Task<string> Post([FromContent]Stream contentStream)
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(contentStream, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        var str = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(str);
    }
    return "OK";
}
```

**How to define stream so it is visible in Swagger UI?**

Here is my implementation of `FromContent` attribute and `ContentParameterBinding` binding:

```cs
public class ContentParameterBinding : HttpParameterBinding
{
    private struct AsyncVoid{}
    public ContentParameterBinding(HttpParameterDescriptor descriptor) : base(descriptor)
    {

    }

    public override Task ExecuteBindingAsync(ModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider,
                                                HttpActionContext actionContext,
                                                CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var binding = actionContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionBinding;

        if (binding.ParameterBindings.Length > 1 ||
            actionContext.Request.Method == HttpMethod.Get)
        {
            var taskSource = new TaskCompletionSource<AsyncVoid>();
            taskSource.SetResult(default(AsyncVoid));
            return taskSource.Task as Task;
        }

        var type = binding.ParameterBindings[0].Descriptor.ParameterType;

        if (type == typeof(HttpContent))
        {
            SetValue(actionContext, actionContext.Request.Content);
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
            tcs.SetResult(actionContext.Request.Content);
            return tcs.Task;
        }
        if (type == typeof(Stream))
        {
            return actionContext.Request.Content
            .ReadAsStreamAsync()
            .ContinueWith((task) =>
            {
                SetValue(actionContext, task.Result);
            });
        }

        throw new InvalidOperationException("Only HttpContent and Stream are supported for [FromContent] parameters");
    }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class FromContentAttribute : ParameterBindingAttribute
{
    public override HttpParameterBinding GetBinding(HttpParameterDescriptor parameter)
    {
        if (parameter == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid parameter");

        return new ContentParameterBinding(parameter);
    }
}
```

> Update

When I create `Stream` using `[FromBody]` is shows correctly in Swagger, however `Stream` is not initiated and `==null`

```cs
[SwaggerOperation("Create")]
[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created)]
public async Task<string> Post([FromBody]Stream contentStream)
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(contentStream, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        var str = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(str);
    }
    return "OK";
}
```

[image: Good Post]

So I want to have the same UI but with my custom attribute which let's me have `Stream` from content.

With my custom attribute it shows without `TextArea` for the parameter but could be tested using Postman and work correctly and `Stream` is available
[image: Bad Post]

Comment: How do you want to show it? Where is the problem? you should clarify  what output you are expecting

Comment: @MegaTron I'm trying to add Test for post, where stream has been created from content body, I'll add examples and pictures

Comment: That whole parameter binding stuff seems like a whole lot of work to avoid doing `var stream = await this.Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()` in the controller method.

Comment: @DarrelMiller, Am I missing the right way to show `var stream = await this.Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();` in swagger UI?

Comment: I don't know what needs to be done to tell Swashbuckle that you are accepting a stream.  However, when we have to make our code more complex to help drive tooling that generates meta data to autogenerate documentation, if feels like we are doing something wrong.

Comment: @DarrelMiller I don't think that [FromContent] attribute makes code more complex as once attribute implementation was created it stay there. For me it was interesting exercise and useful feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inherit your binding from [FormatterParameterBinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.modelbinding.formatterparameterbinding(v=vs.118).aspx) class:

```
public class ContentParameterBinding : FormatterParameterBinding
{
    public ContentParameterBinding(HttpParameterDescriptor descriptor)
            : base(descriptor, 
                   descriptor.Configuration.Formatters, 
                   descriptor.Configuration.Services.GetBodyModelValidator())
    {
    }

    //your code
}
```

Comment: Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1):

Try implementing the interface [`IValueProviderParameterBinding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.modelbinding.ivalueproviderparameterbinding.aspx):

```cs
public class ContentParameterBinding
    : HttpParameterBinding, IValueProviderParameterBinding
{
    public IEnumerable<ValueProviderFactory> ValueProviderFactories
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Descriptor.Configuration.Services.GetValueProviderFactories();
        }
    }
}
```

In my case it helped.
Also it's generally cleaner as it doesn't inherit `FormatterParameterBinding` logic, which may not be required.